# generate invoices for print from xml in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, pdf-generation, razorengine

I have created a xml file from a json post of a rest service and want to use the information to create a pdf file for each -Node in the file/request. How do i generate such a pdf with a template and my given variables? How do i fill the variables in such a manner and how do i create seperate files?
I've looked into [Fo.Net](https://fonet.codeplex.com/) but found that the project seems dead and that the templating is complex.

Then i've looked into PrinceXML and am stuck as how to use a template engine to replace a variable in my template? Could i use [RazorEngine](http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/), and if so, how would the could look like?

Lastly, are there opensource alternatives that are working as good as princeXML?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Test</title></head>
<body>
Hello World! FNR: <!-- how would one add a variable here? --><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PdfPrinter>
  <Document>
    <FNR>FNR</FNR>
    <KNR>KNR</KNR>
    <G>G</G>
    <LN>LN</LN>
</Document>
  <Document>
    <FNR>  00</FNR>
    <KNR>555555</KNR>
    <G>1</G>
    <LN>02</LN>
</Document>
</PdfPrinter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nustache the template html should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Test</title></head>
<body><br>
Hello World! FNR: {{fnr}}, KNR: {{knr}} Uhrzeit: {{date}} <!-- how would one add a variable here? --><br>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

the {{fnr}} tags can be replaced by your own data in code via:

var data = new { knr = "123456", fnr = 10, date = DateTime.Now.ToString() };

or:

```
 internal class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerID {get; set;}
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }



Customer user = new Customer();
Render.FileToFile(templateFile, user, outputFile);
```

this requires the Package Nustache (so: using Nustache.Core; is necessary). It can be found here at [github](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache), or here at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nustache/).